# PHP Fatal error: I'm trying to implement a Form\AbstractType in my Symfony2 application

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Bean\OauthServerBundle\Form\Type\AuthorizeFormType::buildForm() must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface::buildForm(Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) in src/Bean/OauthServerBundle/Form/Type/AuthorizeFormType.php on line 25
```

Not sure why I'm getting this Error. AbstractType::buildForm() takes a FormBuilderInterface, and Symfony2 implements FormBuilderInterface for FormBuilder.

Here's the content of my Source:

```
<?php
namespace Bean\OauthServerBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;

class AuthorizeFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        /* some code ... */
   }

   /* more code ... */
}
```

Comment: In future, you can delve into the source. For example, XDebug gives the location of the files as Symfony/Component/Form, which is where they all are (full path is vendor/symfony/src/symfony/...). You can then easily find 'AbstractType' and see what the signature of the method is that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> FormBuilderInterface, and Symfony2 implements FormBuilderInterface for FormBuilder.

That doesn't change the fact, that `buildForm` has to be declared as in parent class and accept any object that implements `FormBuilderInterface`.

Comment: So just because it accepts FormBuilderInterface as an argument, doesn't mean that you can pass a FormBuilder to it ?

Comment: You can, but in method declaration you have to use `FormBuilderInterface`.

Comment: Is that always the case if you are accepting a class that is bound to an interface?

Comment: This answer is correct, the documentation http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/forms.html is incorrect. The documentation shows the use of the concrete class, not the interface. Don't forget to update the "use" statement too.

Comment: I think they may have updated the documentation. I updated my code based on the most recent version of the documentation and it worked.

Comment: my problem with latest Symfony 2.1 is that I had to include FormBuilderInterface: `use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;`

Answer (score 9):

So the code from symfony book should look like this:

```
namespace Bean\OauthServerBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;

class AuthorizeFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        /* some code ... */
   }

   /* more code ... */
}
```

is this what you mean?